# Using uuidv4 in url to allow non registered users to refund purchases

Tags: web-application, account-security

I know reading that title probably made some of you gag, but let me explain the situation. I was tasked with creating a pretty straightforward storefront web app (php/laravel/stripe for payments) which I have done several times in the past, no big deal. However my past applications all required the user to create an account at checkout so we could handle any refund requests that that customer might have.

Jump forward to my current project, the business customer is adamant about NOT requiring a user account for customers to complete checkout. Ok, I thought...that shouldn't be an issue...except for refunds...how will we handle refunds? Well my solution is currently (and this is still in development it's not in production use until I verify that I'm not completely crazy for doing this) to provide the user a hyperlink within the email they receive at checkout confirmation such as `https://ourdomain.com/refund/9d5f131a-f050-4491-8a30-f6c610deab62` with the uuid being a secret key to the line item record the user wishes to refund. When they click this link, they then have access to request a refund for the item.

Part of me feels like this is fine as this is basically how password resets work (user gets url sent to their email with token they then use to change their password), and I have seen this done in other places (although only for displaying data related to a transaction and not allowing an action). However another part of me is torn as it just doesn't feel right to me to allow "authorization" via a url.

Can anyone confirm whether or not this would be acceptable practice within a production environment?

**EDIT**

There is a timelimit on when a refund can no longer be issued (however it could be several months into the future). The goods sold are currently digital only and are sent to the user upon checkout. Once refunded, the copies sent to the user are invalidated. The only real harm that could be done if this is misused is that someone who obtained the link which should not have it could issue a refund of the item unbeknownst to the purchaser, causing the purchaser's item to become invalidated. At which point they would receive their purchase price at the expense of frustration when their item does not work.

Comment: Is there a time limit before refunds are disabled? Most of the URL-based password resets I've seen only last for a little while.

Comment: Maybe you could explain with your domain knowledge of how this specific store works what harm can be done if this is misused? In my understanding the customer would still have to send the goods back before receiving a refund. And the refund is only possible within some specific time frame so this URL implicitly expires. And whoever has access to this link very likely has also access to the information on what the user has purchased. So what misuse you are trying to prevent?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich question has been updated

Comment: It sounds like the software already has a unique ID/shared secret stored inside of it, so that it can check that its license is still valid.  Could the refund be done inside of the software itself?  Or at least the software provides the URL (in which case, the secret key doesn't have to leave the system, i.e., `example.com/refund/?n=[nonce]&t=[timestamp]&h=[hash(nonce + timestamp + secret)]`

Comment: @Ghedipunk The items are digital vouchers, which are also provided via hyperlink and unique token (`/voucher/{uuid}`)

Comment: Use the Stripe API to provide further authentication detail. A quick look shows there is meta data you maybe able to use, as this cannot be duplicated and would allow you to ask the refundee a question to check they are authorised by who they are and what they have to gain a refund. It's a second factor that the email cannot provide as that just proves a have factor.